# How can I pass a variable from the Python-Behave step?

Tags: python, bdd, python-behave

Basically I wrote a step called
`@When("I go to {url}")`

Then I called it from the feature file using
`When I go to http://youtube.com` and it worked

But I want to call it using
`When I go to YouTube`

Same would happen with css selectors (For `Then logo is visible` looks prettier than `Then div#id.class is visible`)

How can I link a map file containing this css selectors and URL's as variables for my steps to use?
Something like this:

```
YouTube = "http://youtube.com"
logo = "div#id.class"
```

I tried this

```
def before_all(context):
    global YouTube
    YouTube = "http://youtube.com"
```

And then I would `eval(url)` inside the step but it kept saying YouTube was not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a dictionary of predefined URLs instead of variables. Add this to your steps implementation file:

```
websites = {'youtube': 'http://youtube.com', 'somesite': 'http://somesite.com'}

@When("I go to {website}")
def when_i_go_to_website(context, website):
    context.url = websites[website]
```

`context.url` will be available in all followings steps.

You might want to surround the code line with `try` / `except` to catch KeyErrors.